# spark 2.2.1 - The connection pool plugin of type "BONECP" was not found in the CLASSPATH

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have created a `jar`  in `spark 2.2.1`, which has been created at `target/scala-2.11.Jar`. It was running fine But I cannot run the created files. It is throwing below exception of `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException`:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:266)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:136)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:587)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.emptyDataFrame$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:265)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.emptyDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.emptyDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:179)
        at edu.am.bigdata.reader.DataReader.read(DataReader.scala:35)
        at ad2.heatmap.services.ChartConverterServer$ChartConverterService.doPost(ChartConverterServer.scala:136)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:430)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234)
        ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        ... 64 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:587)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:788)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:325)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:282)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:240)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:286)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
        ... 98 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Attempt to invoke the "BONECP" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : The connection pool plugin of type "BONECP" was not found in the CLASSPATH!
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:259)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:131)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:85)
        ... 116 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: The connection pool plugin of type "BONECP" was not found in the CLASSPATH!
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:234)
```

This is the build file:

```
name := "Converter"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.2.1"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % sparkVersion % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-graphx_2.11" % sparkVersion

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % sparkVersion

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % sparkVersion

libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.11" % "1.5.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-xml_2.11" % "0.4.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.3.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % sparkVersion

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.paho" % "org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3" % "1.1.1"

resolvers += "MQTT Repository" at "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"

libraryDependencies += "com.googlecode.json-simple" % "json-simple" % "1.1.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "8.1.14.v20131031"

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-servlet" % "8.1.14.v20131031"

libraryDependencies += "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.0.1"

libraryDependencies += "javax.persistence" % "persistence-api" % "1.0"

// required at run time by hive - datanucleus

libraryDependencies += "org.datanucleus" % "datanucleus-core" % "3.2.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.datanucleus" % "datanucleus-api-jdo" % "3.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.datanucleus" % "datanucleus-rdbms" % "3.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.35"

libraryDependencies += "org.reflections" % "reflections" % "0.9.9-RC1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.6.5"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client
//libraryDependencies += "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-client" % "1.9.1"

//libraryDependencies += "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-core" % "1.9.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.8.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.stratio.datasource" % "spark-mongodb_2.11" % "0.11.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-cypher" % "3.3.0-alpha05"

libraryDependencies += "neo4j-contrib" % "neo4j-spark-connector" % "2.0.0-M2"

libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "4.0.0"
```

I need to resolve this error but not sure how. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need more than one Spark jar and the scala jar to run Spark code. Please show the command you used to build the jar, run the jar, and a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: "sbt assembly" command used to build the jar and
"nohup java -cp ChartConverter-assembly-1.0.jar:jars/* 'main class name' &" used to run my jar

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the SBT file?

Comment: @Aswathy any success with this error? I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because datanucleus-core library cannot properly initialize plugins when application is bundled in to single jar and DataNucleus* jars are inside application jar. 
I've created simple project to demonstrate the problem - you can find it [here](https://github.com/piotrchowaniec/spark-hive-jar). In my case problem is in `org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry` class as it cannot find the plugin.xml file when path is in form `jar:file:<path_to_app_jar>!/<path_inside_jar>!/plugin.xml`.

Unfortunately there is no fix for this in the datanucleus-core project.

I've fixed this to be able to run my application - don't know if this help everyone - but in case if anyone would like to see my solution please check [my fork](https://github.com/piotrchowaniec/datanucleus-core/releases/tag/datanucleus-core-3.2.13.1). The fix is done based on 3.2.13 version cause later ones have changed API and Spark expects the older one (at least in my case). To build datanucleus-core with fix one have to use Java 7.